# How to set html.displayfor() style attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, styles, html-helper, displayfor

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4.0.And my problem is i am not getting a way to define a color of DisplayFor html attribute.

I have a HTML.DispalyFor() which is generating dynamic checkboxes and i want to set its background color to gray.

I have tried to do that by style property but i am not getting the result.I have try below thing :

```
new {@class="clsColor"}

Style{
   .clsColor = "backgroundcolor:gray";
}
```

Can any one help me out on this ?

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: If your wanting to set the style in the page (as opposed to using a style sheet), use the `style` tag e.g.`<style>.clsColor{backgroundcolor:gray;}</style>`

Comment: plz post relevent code here...

Answer (score 0):

First of all use **style** tags properly. You can set background color by **background-color** not backgroundcolor:

```
<style>
.clsColor
{
background-color: gray;
}
</style>
```